# Stacked bar Chart in Angular4

Tags: angular, d3.js, typescript-typings, stacked-chart

I am trying to apply a d3.js stacked bar chart to Angular4. Looking at the [stack()](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#_stack) reference on [github](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#_stack), I have this inside my component

```
  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log("change detected");
    let self = this;
    let d3 = this.d3;
    let d3ParentElement: any;
    let svg: any;
    let width: number = 500;
    let height: number = 150;

    if (this.parentNativeElement !== null) {
      d3.select("svg").remove();
      svg = d3.select(this.parentNativeElement)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

      var datas = [
        {month: new Date(2015, 0, 1), apples: 3840, bananas: 1920, cherries: 960, dates: 400},
        {month: new Date(2015, 1, 1), apples: 1600, bananas: 1440, cherries: 960, dates: 400},
        {month: new Date(2015, 2, 1), apples:  640, bananas:  960, cherries: 640, dates: 400},
        {month: new Date(2015, 3, 1), apples:  320, bananas:  480, cherries: 640, dates: 400}
      ];

      var stack = d3.stack()
      .keys(["apples", "bananas", "cherries", "dates"])
      .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
      .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

      var series = stack(datas);
}
```

Obviously this is just a snapshot. 'datas' in the last line is causing this,[image] But why are the 'series' and possibly 'stack' variables having difficulty with the keys in the 'datas' array?

Also I am using the [d3-ng2-service](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have succeeded in getting rid of the error using,

```
let stack: any;
let series: any;
```

at the beginning of the file and removing the 'var' from each.